# Symfony2 handle jQuery serialized Form sent with ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to handle the form sent with ajax
here is my ajax post code:

```
     $.post("{{ path('order_ad_banner') }}",
        {form: $('#adOrderForm').serialize(), url: "{{ url }}"},
        function (data) {
            $('#formWindow').html(data);
        }
    );
```

here my request handling:

```
$receivedForm = $request->request->get('form', null);
...
$form = $this->createForm(new OrderType(), $order);
if($receivedForm) {
    $form->submit($receivedForm);
}
```

unfortunately this binding doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$receivedForm = $request->request->get('adOrderForm', null);
...
$form = $this->createForm(new OrderType(), $order);
if($receivedForm) {
    $form->submit($receivedForm);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

found my own solution:

```
$.post("{{ path('order_ad_banner') }}",
        $('#adOrderForm').serialize() + "&" + $.param({url: "{{ url }}"}),
        function (data) {
            $('#formWindow').html(data);
        }
);
```

and

```
$receivedForm = $request->request->get('adOrder', null);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some easier solutions.

Do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: route,
        data: $('#adOrderForm').serialize(),
        success: function (data)
        {

        }
 });
```

And in symfony controller:

```
public function someAction(Request $request)
{
    ...
    $form = $this->createForm(new OrderType(), $order);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) 
    {
         ...
    }
}
```